# Recuperación de contraseña con firebase en una pagina web

Tags: firebase, backend

Quiero que cuando firebase me envíe el link de recuperación de contraseña me mande a mi web (Esto ya lo tengo hecho) y lo que me falta es enviar los datos a firebase para hacer el cambio claro todo desde mi web.

¿Saben si se puede hacer?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje de programación piensas hacerlo (desde la web)? Firebase tiene APIs para ciertos lenguajes, y tiene también una API REST.

Comment: La estoy haciendo con react